# Probability that $X \geq 10$, if $E(X^3) = 100$.

Tags: probability

On my last test, there was a question:

> Find an upper bound on the probability that $X \geq 10$, if $E(X^3) = 100$.

I used the fact that $$P(X \geq c) = P(f(X) \geq f(c)) \leq \frac{E[f(X)]}{f(c)},$$ where $f$ is non-negative and monotonically increasing.
If you substitute $f(x) = x^3$ and $c=10$, it turns out that $P(X \geq 10) \leq \frac{100}{1000} = \frac{1}{10}$.

However, $f(x) = x^3$ meets the given conditions only for $x \geq 0$, so I have doubts whether this is a good solution.
Is it correct and if not, what could be the other approach?

Comment: "...from above, ..." What is that?

Comment: @callculus42 that's the upper bound. Sorry ;)

Comment: Was there an assumption that $X\ge 0$?

Comment: @RobertIsrael no, there was no such assumption.

Comment: Technically speaking, $1$ is always an upper bound on any probability.  The question should be more specific.

Comment: @achillehui What do you mean? $1000$ is not what we want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you were given that $P(X\ge 0)=1$, then your solution would be correct. You noticed a logical gap in your proof, that the function $f(x)=x^3$ does not satisfy $f(x)\ge 0$ for all $x\in \mathbb R$. To remedy this, define
$$
g(x)=x^3 \text{ if }x\ge 0\text{ and } g(x)=0\text{ otherwise }.
$$
You can check that $g$ is nonnegative and monotone (weakly) increasing. With the assumption that $P(X\ge 0)$, it follows that $X^3=g(X)$ with probability one, and that $X\ge 10$ if and only if $g(X)\ge g(10)$. Therefore,
$$
P(X\ge 10)=P(g(X)\ge g(10))\le \frac{E[g(X)]}{g(10)}=\frac{E[X^3]}{10^3}=\frac1{10}.
$$
However, without the assumption that $P(X\ge 0)$, there is not enough information to give a nontrivial bound on $P(X\ge 10)$. This means that the problem is ill-formed, and unsolvable. You should complain to the person who wrote the test.

To see this, choose $p$ such that $0<p<1$, and define $X$ as follows.

> Flip a coin whose probability of heads is $p$. If it the coins is heads, then $X=\sqrt[3]{\frac{1000}p}$. If the coins is tails, then $X=-\sqrt[3]{\frac{900}{1-p}}$.

Note that
$$
E[X^3]=p\cdot \left(\sqrt[3]{\frac{1000}p}\right)^3+(1-p)\cdot \left(-\sqrt[3]{\frac{900}{1-p}}\right)^3=100,
$$
so $X$ satisfies the condition of the problem.
However, $P(X\ge 10)=p$. Since we can choose $p$ to be as close to $1$ as we want, this is a family of examples which shows that no reasonable upper bound on $P(X\ge 10)$ is possible.